# Rails mkdir & permissions not working well

Tags: ruby, file-permissions

I have this piece of code

```
folder = File.join(SOME_PATH, "some_sufolder")
Dir.mkdir(folder, 0770) unless File.exists?(folder)
```

I use it from a user `my_user` to create directories inside a folder which has the following permissions

```
drwxrwsr-x 19 my_user some_group
```

However, the newly created directories are

```
 drwxr-s---
```

So Chmod 750 not 770 !!

What the heck is going on ?

And also, I do not understand why I need to enter `0770` and not just `770` (which does weird things otherwise), what is the first digit doing ? I couldn't find any ref of this in the Ruby documentation

Comment: leading zero means octal literal

Comment: From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-mkdir): `The permissions may be modified by the value of File::umask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [`File::umask`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-umask) it's probably set to `18`(dec or `022` octal), it is subtracted from the permissions you set in `#mkdir`

```
(0770 & ~(022)).to_s(8) #=> 750
```

Comment: Could you elaborate ? Why devs would set it to 18 by default ? WHat value shoud I set it to ?

Comment: 022 is default root umask in linux, 02 is default user umask. I believe this is taken from the `$ umask` at the start time of the ruby script.

Comment: Set it to `02`, it will limit your permissions to `rwxrwxr-x`. Or `0`... (Not sure if there are some security issues with that. AFAIK there's nothing criminal if you always set permissions when creating files inside the program.)